# Multi Line with no sum

Tags: sql

Me again!
I have the following query which currently spreads over two lines for the same record, I would like to merge it onto one line as per the below example

```
DECLARE @period_from INT
SET @period_from = 201400

DECLARE @period_to INT
SET @period_to = 201414

Declare @length INT
Set @length = '12'

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '%[^-a-zA-Z0-9() ]%'

SELECT 
'dim_2' AS dim_2, 
NULL AS dim_3,
NULL AS ext_ref, 
* FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND dim_2 LIKE @query AND voucher_no='170075928' AND agrtid='9662846'
UNION
SELECT 
NULL as dim_2,
'dim_3' AS dim_3,  
NULL AS ext_ref,
* FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND dim_3 LIKE @query AND voucher_no='170075928'AND agrtid='9662846'
UNION
SELECT 
NULL AS dim_2, 
NULL AS dim_3,
'ext_ref' AS ext_ref,
* FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND ext_ref LIKE @query AND voucher_no='170075928'AND agrtid='9662846'
```

This returns the following

```
dim_2 | dim_3 | ext_ref | data |...
----------------------------------
dim_2 | NULL | NULL    | data | .....
NULL  | NULL | ext_ref | data | .....
```

I would like

```
dim_2 | dim_3 | ext_ref | data |...
----------------------------------
dim_2 | NULL | ext_ref | data | .....
```

Any help would be appreciated

I'm using MS SQL Server

Jim

Comment: What happens when both rows have a value that differs? Who wins?

Comment: @Jim: It seems you're in love with UNION glues. However this only removes *duplicates*. By using the constants 'dim_2' etc. you make sure there are *no* duplicates. And even without them, with * from table1, do you expect two records to be completly equal over all columns? Your SQL statement kind of contradicts itself. This is the second request here I've read from you. They are very technical and both times you seem to think in the wrong direction. Better tell us about table contents and what you want to achieve actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, this could be simplified this way.

```
select 
case when dim_2  LIKE @query then 'dim_2' end as dim_2,
case when dim_3 LIKE @query then 'dim_3' end as dim_3,
case when ext_ref LIKE @query then 'ext_ref' end as ext_ref,
*
FROM 
table1 
WHERE client = 'CL'
 AND period >= @period_from 
 AND @period_to <= @period_to 
 AND voucher_no='170075928'
 AND agrtid='9662846'
-- and maybe add
--(and dim_2 like @query or dim_3 like @query or ext_ref like @query)
```